# Spring Data MongoDB Query based on id of inner document

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

Considering the following entitis (EventReactions, EventLog ):

```
public class EventReaction extends Entity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private EventLog eventLog;
    ....    
    //getters and setters
}
```

and

```
public class EventLog extends Entity {

    @Id
    private String id;
    ....
    //getters and setters
}
```

I expected the following interface

```
public interface EventReactionRepository extends MongoRepository<T , String>{

    Optional<EventReaction> findByEventLog_Id(String id)

}
```

returns the eventReactions which their eventLog id is `id`. However, it is already exist in mogoDB my query returns nothing! Is my query correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to

```
Optional<EventReaction> findByEventLogId(ObjectId id);
```

Get `Optional<EventReaction>` from

```
Optional<EventReaction> result= eventReactionRepository.findByEventLogId(new ObjectId("document-storage-id"));
```